# QTest - Unable to pass Qt::Enter to QPushButton

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, qtestlib

I'm creating an automated test application using QTest Library. I'm able to simulate key presses on the application except when it gets to a window having QDialogButtonBox (Save, and Cancel). 
Here's my sample code:

```
std::auto_ptr<MainForm> myForm( new MainForm( 3, 3 ));
myForm->show();
QTest::keyPress(myForm.get(), Qt::Key_0, NULL, 1000);
QTest::keyRelease(myForm.get(), Qt::Key_0, NULL, 100);
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QCOMPARE(QString(pWin->objectName()), QString("MyMainForm"));
```

now when it gets to the next window, it has several controls where the input focus is on  a text edit control. When I press Enter, it presses the "Save" button. So theoretically, if I should pass Qt::Enter to the Form, it should press the "Save" button as well. However when I try to pass a keyPress:

```
QTest::keyPress(pWin, Qt::Key_Enter, 1000);
```

nothing happens... what do you think is going on? I've tried setFocus() to the button but nothing happens as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in QDialogButtonBox you may get needed button with

```
 QPushButton * QDialogButtonBox::button ( StandardButton which )
```

and then call it's SetFocus method.
If you can't access QDialogButtonBox directly, you may get it with

```
QList<T> QObject::findChildren ( const QString & name = QString() )
```

or even get buttons themself with this method...

Comment: I tried getting the list of buttons and setting focus to any of the buttons. But passing Qt::Enter doesn't do anything... :(

Comment: QCOMPARE(QString(pWin->objectName()), QString("MyMainForm")); - this is the main window... maybe you need to get your popup window id and send command to it? Or you just not posted that piece of code?

Comment: whenever I call QTest::keyPress(), I'm already sending a keypress to the window.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to send the key event to the button or line edit instead of the parent window.

```
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QTest::keyPress(pwin, Qt::Key_0, NULL, 1000);
QTest::keyRelease(pwin, Qt::Key_0, NULL, 100);
```

I have to say that the documentation is not clear, but it works for me this way.